# react-native-community/voice giving error on speech to text

Tags: react-native, speech-to-text

[My setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEePq.png)
[My setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNOeX.png)

If you're encountering issues with speech recognition in a React Native app, ensure that the microphone setting is enabled in your emulator. Go to the emulator settings and enable "Virtual microphone uses host audio." Lack of microphone access can cause speech recognition to fail silently. This simple setting adjustment resolved my persistent issues with speech recognition, saving me valuable time and frustration.